# Radiobutton Text alignment Issue

Tags: asp.net, text, radio-button

I am working in asp.net and have radiobutton list and I want to align their text as I require.
Here is what I have currently:

[image]

I want to make them like this:

[image]

**EDIT:**
Secondly, when I click Ages From radiobutton, I display a div against this like:

[image]

and when I click back to All Ages radio button, I want to hide that div. But SelectedIndexChanged doesn't work second time and onwards. It only works first time.

Code of aspx:

```
<table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdoAge" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" 
                                    onselectedindexchanged="rdoAge_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" >
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="All Ages" Value="All Ages" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="Ages From" Value="Ages From"></asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:RadioButtonList>
                            </td>
                            <div id="divAge" runat="server" visible="false">
                                <td>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtAgeFrom" runat="server" CssClass="textEntry2" MaxLength="3" Width="65"></asp:TextBox>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblTo" runat="server" Text="To"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtAgeTo" runat="server" CssClass="textEntry2" MaxLength="3" Width="65"></asp:TextBox>
                                </td>
                            </div>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
```

Code of cs file:

```
protected void rdoAge_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (rdoAge.SelectedValue)
        {
            case "All Ages":
                divAge.Visible = false;
                break;
            case "Ages From":
                divAge.Visible = true;
                break;
        }
    }
```

I'll be grateful if anyone suggests something useful for this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was the problem of missing closing tag. I must have missed a closing tag of some control. I re-added all controls with taking care of closing tags. Now it is working fine.

Thanks all for helping.

Answer (score 0):

try using css sytel

```
<style type="text/css">
 table.radioWithProperWrap input
 {    
      float: left;
 }

 table.radioWithProperWrap label
 {    
      word-wrap: break-word;

 }
</style>
<asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" CssClass="radioWithProperWrap" ....>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply but this css is not working. The output is the same as was previously

Comment: Please see my edited question, if I ignore the alignment problem, I have another issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
 switch (rdoAge.SelectedItem.Text)
```

In the Source Code, Define the Update Panel like this:

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
```

and then in the OnSelectedIndexChanged event, add
       UpdatePanel1.Update();

Comment: it is not the problem of div. It is not working for simple controls as well liks text box or DDL

Comment: In the onselectedindexchanged event add one line as
        UpdatePanel1.Update();

Comment: It throws exception: `The Update method can only be called on UpdatePanel with ID 'upConsumerSummaryReport' when UpdateMode is set to Conditional.`

Comment: still the same problem ... :(

Comment: there is no error. Just the same as was previously like when I click back to All Ages radio button, nothing happens

Comment: How many Update Panel have u used? Could u post the SourceCode Containing the Update Panel?

Comment: `<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upConsumerSummaryReport" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>` Im using just one update panel

Comment: U didn't give UpdateMode="Conditional" in your UpdatePanel tag.
Give it as
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upConsumerSummaryReport" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">

Comment: place the trigger tag after the 
</ContentTemplate><Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="radiobuttonlist" />
    </Triggers>
</UpdatePanel>

Comment: Thanks Thevan, it is working now. But there is one problem, it looks like page is posting back that is not desired in my scenario. Any idea?

Comment: Place one UpdatePanel Common to the full WebPage:
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upWebPage" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
</ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

Comment: Hi, Did u get the answer? I really couldn't understand the issue. Anyway as a Beginner, Dont hestitate to ask help from your seniors.

Comment: yes I got the answer but stackoverflow is not allowing me to mark it as answer until 2 days will pass. And u r right, I hesitate in taking help from seniors. :S