# Radiobutton Text alignment Issue in chrome and firefox

Tags: radio-button, vertical-alignment

I am facing the same problem posted in the following link. But that answer doesn't work for me.

[Radiobutton Text alignment Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183867/radiobutton-text-alignment-issue)

This allignment issue is happen only in safari, chrome and firefox

Code:

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="StorageRadio" GroupName="FormatRadios" 
 TextAlign="Right" Text="Export for storage" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I got solution by adding the following style

Code:

```
label, input[type="radio"] 
{
  font-size: 12px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-top: -1px;
}
```